# Как создать метод без использовать параметров?

Tags: java

```
public void setMenuItemVisibility(String fragmentTag, boolean visibility, Menu menu) {

}
```

Можно ли в Java используя аннотацию создать параметр в методе, чтобы при необходимости использовать его?// Сейчас я знаю лишь один способ создать. создать такой же метод но чтобы хотя бы на 1 параметр было больше или меньше.

Код слишком большой получается.

Comment: Что именно вы хотите получить в итоге? Сейчас у вас есть метод, который принимает 3 параметра, первый из которых типа `String`, второй - `boolean`, а третий - `Menu`. Какой список параметров вы хотите получить?

Comment: То что вы описали невозможно. Ну есть 2 способа выполнить данную задачу . 1. Перегрузить метод (создать 2 методы с разным каличиством параметров). 2. Создайте 1 метод с 4 параметрами и случае если вам данный параметер не нужен передавайте null. А в теле самого метода проверяйте на наличие значение и выполняйте ту логику которая вам нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно Вам помогут [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). Используя их, можно построить метод следующего вида:

```
public <T> void newMethod(T... parameterList) {
}
```

В данном случае Вы сможете передать любое количество параметров, в том числе и Ваш список.

```
newMethod("fragment", true, new Menu());
```

Но все же прибегать к такому виду Франкенштейнов (именно с точки зрения архитектуры и постановки задачи), на мой взгляд, не стоит, поскольку это усложняет читабельность кода, делает его непредсказуемым и лишает объектнориентированности.

Answer (score 3):

> Сейчас я знаю лишь один способ создать. создать такой же метод но чтобы хотя бы на 1 параметр было больше или меньше.

Этот вариант выглядит наиболее "верным" и "некостыльным".

> Код слишком большой получается.

Ну почему же - вам не требуется дублировать логику в каждом методе - вы будете вызвать метод с бо'льшим количеством аргументов, передавая в качестве одного/неск. аргументов значение по умолчанию. Т.е. по 3 строки кода на "версию" метода.

```
public void setMenuItemVisibility(String fragmentTag, boolean visibility, Menu menu) {
    //логика
}

public void setMenuItemVisibility(String fragmentTag, boolean visibility) {
    setMenuItemVisibility(fragmentTag, visibility, defaultMenuValue1);
}

public void setMenuItemVisibility(String fragmentTag) {
    setMenuItemVisibility(fragmentTag, defaultVisibilityValue);
    //либо, если например для такого случая defaultMenuValue2 != defaultMenuValue1
    setMenuItemVisibility(fragmentTag, defaultVisibilityValue, defaultMenuValue2);
}
```